# Linux CentOS 7 - Configuration of httpd.conf file through .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, centos7, httpd.conf

1. I need to configure through `.htaccess` in `Linux CentOS  7` that my `info.php` file is shown without extension. That is, calling `http://server address/info` instead of calling `http://server address/info.php`.
2. Also, in `.htaccess`, add that `phpinformation` redirects to `info`. That is, `http://server address/phpinformation` redirects to `http://server address/info`.

I have followed the part of the following [article](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/set-up-basic-authentication-in-apache-using-htaccess-on-centos-7/).

In the `httpd.conf` file, I have changed `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride AuthConfig`.

What are the next steps?

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite your files you should overrite the **FileInfo** type of directive, not the **AuthConfig** ones (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride for references)

Enable the **mod_rewrite** module in the apache configuration
and in the .htaccess file use a similar configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^phpinformation$ info.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^info$ info.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

A more general configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^phpinformation$ info.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The first rewrite rule is the same, if you have to serve a request with an url containing just phpinformation, rewrite it to info.php and serve that url instead. The L modifier means that the rewriter does not need to search for additional rewriting and can just ask apache to serve the resulting (info.php) rule.

The second rule is a bit different, the rewrite engine perform the rewrite only if ALL the previuous condition are met. In this case the original url does not resolve to an existing file (!-f) or directory (!-d).
If the file/directory exists it will be served as usual

You may also want to perform an external redirect to force the client to access to an official url for a resource, in this case the first example can change in something similar:

```
RedirectMatch ^/phpinformation$ /info
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^info$ info.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Why do not use the RedirectMatch for both the urls? The reason is that the client user sees the redirected url on the browser and thus the .php suffix, we need to rid off, would pop up again.

### References

[Mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
[AllowOverride documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
[RedirectMatch documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

Comment: Does not works is quite vague :-)?
Have you mod_rewrite enabled in Apache, Have you configured the directory with AllowOverride FileInfo? At least the first rewrite rule is straightforward and should surely match.

Comment: I've just spot a mistype in the latest Rewrite and fixed it, please retry.
The first rule `http://yourserver/phpinformation` had to work though

Comment: I have done the following for question 1 (I am still figuring out how to do question 2): In the httpd.conf file, I have set AllowOverride All. In the .htaccess file, I have written the following: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info$ info.php [NC]. Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7

Comment: Your rule configurations are working properly, thanks. But the following snippet is also working: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info$ info.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^phpinformation$ info.php [L]. What does [L] stands for in the line RewriteRule ^phpinformation$ info.php [L]?

Comment: It means that the rewrite is the last one to apply before serving the url. Without it the rewrite engine keep trying to rewrite the url with the conditions and rules following the [L]ed one.

Comment: @user9408826 just updated the answer with the last information

Comment: Actually, question 2 (redirection) doesn't work. After calling 'http://server address/phpinformation', it should call 'http://server address/info'. That doesn't work. It stays on 'http://server address/phpinformation'.

Comment: ... also, these solutions don't hide .php extension if you call it as 'server address/info.php'. Try the following: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: ... is there a mistake in your 'RedirectMatch "^/info$" "/phpinformation" '?

Comment: remove the trailing / from the regular expression

Comment: RedirectMatch "^info$" "/phpinformation" and it doesn't work.

Comment: I beg yourdon, I was blind! Just tested and fixed the directive, the quotation weren't needed. Inverted the flow of redirection too, i.e phpinformation => info => info.php

Comment: Still doesn't work (redirection). Here is the snippet: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RedirectMatch ^/phpinformation$ /info
Look at the last line.

Comment: The directive are enforced in order of appearance, one for line.
**T**he RedirectMatch one needs to be the first, as in the example I gave you, even before the if mod_rewrite line, as it is in the mod_alias module, loaded by default in Apache.

Comment: Could you please show how to redirect non existing link "http://192.168.1.120/phpinformation" to "http://192.168.1.120/info". I gave you the server address. Here is the working code for hiding .php extension: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]