# .htaccess file is not working with hostgator

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration, centos, web-hosting

I have migrated my CRM application (developed PHP) from hostgator VPS to hostinger,
My application Folder structure is crm\leadstracer1.1{other php files}. I had kept a  .htaccess file in crm folder, to avoid '.php' extension on URL, that was working fine on hostgator. But after migrating hostinger its not getting work, I am using CentOs server, I tried instructions from following links
[Linux CentOS 7 - Configuration of httpd.conf file through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984999/linux-centos-7-configuration-of-httpd-conf-file-through-htaccess)
[Codeigniter URL rewriting .htaccess is not working on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710569/codeigniter-url-rewriting-htaccess-is-not-working-on-centos)
But nothing get work out.
Please see the content of my .htacess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ leadstracer1.1/views/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ leadstracer1.1/views/$1.php
```

It would be great if someoone help me regrding this
Thanks

Comment: try to use phpinfo(); to check if mod_rewrite is active

Comment: I tried alreay, I can see  mod_rewrite  in Loaded Modules

Comment: yup, It works if i try to add .php on URL

Comment: please add examples of URLs getting 404 and URLs that work fine

Comment: The simplest way to test if apache uses your .htaccess file, or if it otherwise ignores it, is to intentionally break it. Edit the .htaccess file, so the first line reads 'Test or anything'. If you see 500 internal server error, that's actually good! This means that Apache is parsing the .htaccess file

Comment: I have migrated to Hostinger and have this exact same issue it is not recognising htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly configured your httpd.conf or virtualhost conf file to allow the use of htacces file?

Usually you have to change it to make it works.

There should be a directive called  `AllowOverride none` that must be configured as `All` for example

Comment: Shared hosting doesn't have this level of control with most hosts.